# How to submit an ajax form to a different url

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an ajax form where the select controls actually call the ajax functions and set the other controls dynamically. The submit button does not work at all right now, but I need it to submit the form to the action url normally [not submit to the ajax url]

How is this done correctly?

**UPDATE:** the urls are in the same domain.

here is the form:

```
<div class="sidebar quick-search">

  <h3><span class="color-primary">Quick</span> Search</h3>

  <form role="form" id="searchform" method="post" action="[[~99]]">


  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Manufacturer:</label>
          <select class="form-control input-sm filter-group" data-filter-group="make" id="vehiclemake" name="vehiclemake" >
              [[+vehiclemake]]
          </select>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Model:</label>
          <select class="form-control input-sm filter-group" data-filter-group="model" id="vehiclemodel" name="vehiclemodel" >
              [[+vehiclemodel]]
          </select>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Year:</label>
          <select class="form-control input-sm filter-group" data-filter-group="year" id="vehicleyear" name="vehicleyear" >
              [[+vehicleyear]]
          </select>
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Body Type:</label>
          <select class="form-control input-sm filter-group" data-filter-group="bodytype" id="vehiclebodytype" name="vehiclebodytype" >
              [[+vehiclebodytype]]
          </select>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Transmission:</label>
          <select class="form-control input-sm filter-group" data-filter-group="transmission" id="vehicletransmission" name="vehicletransmission" >
              [[+vehicletransmission]]
          </select>
          </div>
      </div>
      <!--div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Mileage:</label>
          <select class="form-control input-sm filter-group" data-filter-group="mileage" id="exampleInputEmail1" name="select" >
                [[+vehiclemileage]]
          </select>
          </div>
      </div-->
  </div>

  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group submit">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary form-control input-sm" id="search-form-search">Search</button>
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group submit">
          <button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary form-control input-sm" id="search-form-reset" >Reset</button>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>

  </form>

</div>
```

and the ajax bit:

```
$('.filter-group').change(function() {

    var form = $('#searchform');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        //url: form.attr( 'action' ),
        url: '[[~131]]',
        data: form.serialize(),
        dataType  : "json",
        cache: false,


        beforeSend: function() {
            console.log( 'before send' );
        },

        success: function(data, status) {

            $.each(data, function( key, value ) {

                //console.log(key);

                populateSelectControls(key, value);

            });

        },

        error: function(data){
            //this would be a 404 error!    
            console.log('hellooo - this is an error!!!');
        }
    });
});


function populateSelectControls(optKey, optValues){

    var $control = $('#' + optKey);

    $control.empty(); 

    //$control.append($("<option></option>").attr('value', 'null'));
    $control.append($("<option></option>").attr('value', '').text('select/clear'));

    $.each(optValues, function(key, value) {

        //console.log('key = ' + key + ' value = ' + value);

        //var mycontrol = $control.append($("<option></option>").attr("value", '.'+key).text(key));

        $("<option />", {
            value: '.' + key,
            text: key,
            selected: value === 'selected'
        }).appendTo($control);

    });
```

Comment: What dpes the `[[~131]]` mean in the ajax url, is that some sort of server side templating code ? Are the url's on the same domain or a different domain ?

Comment: Looks like you almost had the solution with url: form.attr('action') - is there a reason you commented that out?

Comment: if the urls are from same domain there is not much of a problem, it's usual ajax, but if the domains are different use a Reverse Proxy http://www.apachetutor.org/admin/reverseproxies

Comment: @all, thanks. the [[~1331]] & [[~99]] are server side code for modx resource ids. Modx parses them into actual urls [note they are different but in the same domain]

Comment: @headlikearock yes, that would submit the form to the form action url, not the ajax url. the ajax url just handles changing the select options. the form action url will perform an actual search and display vehicle inventory.

Comment: @SeanKimball - your question states that you want to "submit the form to the action url". Not clear on which url you would like to submit to since you seem to already have the way to submit to the action url.

Comment: @headlikearock, the select controls submit the form to the ajax url, which all works fine [they just set the options on the other select boxes] however when the submit button is clicked, the for should post to the action url [not the ajax url]

Comment: you should populate form in one ajax, and submit the final form in a different ajax or using submit button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like so?

```
jQuery('#search-form-search').click(function() {
    var form = jQuery('#searchform');
    var url = jQuery('#searchform').attr('action');
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: form.serialize(),
        dataType  : "json",
        cache: false
    });
});
```

actually I think you can just do:

```
  jQuery('#search-form-search').click(function() {
        jQuery( "#searchform" ).submit();
     });
```